# AppleScript / Shell Script to read 'curl -L' data

Tags: terminal, applescript, command-line

I have Dropbox file with two lines of data that I'd like to parse into two variables. The following function should have the right logic but doesn't seem to work:

```
set versionFile to do shell script ("curl -L 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/5eugzgr1alfgsp9/version.txt?dl=1'")
set lineDelimiter to read versionFile using delimiter return
repeat with oneLine in lineDelimiter
    if length of oneLine is greater than 0 then
        set variable to oneLine
        log "variable: " & variable
    end if
end repeat
```

**Error:**
`error "Can’t make \"1.0.0.2
 www.example.com/download-link-here\" into type file." number -1700 from "1.0.0.2
 www.example.com/download-link-here" to file`

Any help is greatly appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: As coded, `versionFile` is a _variable_ that contains the contents of the _file_ not the _file_ itself and you're using the `read` _command_ improperly, as it reads data from a _file_, not a _variable_.

Answer (score 1):

As coded, `versionFile` is a *variable* that contains the contents of the *file* not the *file* itself and you're using the `read` *command* improperly, as it reads data from a *file*, not a *variable*.

Change:

```
set lineDelimiter to read versionFile using delimiter return
```

To:

```
set lineDelimiter to paragraphs of versionFile
```

---

```
set versionFile to do shell script ("curl -L 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/5eugzgr1alfgsp9/version.txt?dl=1'")
set lineDelimiter to paragraphs of versionFile
repeat with oneLine in lineDelimiter
    if length of oneLine is greater than 0 then
        set variable to oneLine
        log "variable: " & variable
    end if
end repeat
```

---

Results:

```
tell current application
    do shell script "curl -L 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/5eugzgr1alfgsp9/version.txt?dl=1'"
        --> "1.0.0.2
www.example.com/download-link-here"
    (*variable: 1.0.0.2*)
    (*variable: www.example.com/download-link-here*)
end tell
```

---

Since the `versionFile` *variable* contains the *text* contents of the *file*, then in this case to work with it, use the *elements* of *text objects*, one of which is [`paragraph`](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH1g-DontLinkElementID_616) and in the context defined as:

> A series of characters beginning immediately after either the first character after the end of the preceding paragraph or the beginning of the text and ending with either a carriage return character (\r), a linefeed character (\n), a return/linefeed pair (\r\n), or the end of the text. The Unicode "paragraph separator" character (U+2029) is not supported.